# Dismiss View After Switching Segmented Control To Different View?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have three view controllers that use a segmented control to switch between them using modal segues.  From what I can tell, the more a user switches between them, the more memory the app chomps up because it keeps adding new views without discarding the previous ones.

To fix this, I tried adding `dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES` to the end of my switching method.  This resulted in a warning - *"Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller  while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!"*

Any ideas how to do this so that it functions similar to a tab bar?

```
- (IBAction)switchTab:(id)sender {

    UISegmentedControl *segControll = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;
    if (segControll.selectedSegmentIndex==2)
    {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segToSecondView" sender:keyValue];

    }
    else if (segControll.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segToThirdView" sender:keyValue];
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Don't use modal presentation. Create your own custom container view controller, and use the method 
`transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:`
 to switch between child view controllers.

You should be able to use a container view controller and an embed segue to hook up your "root" view controller (The first view controller displayed as a child) and then user the above method to switch to different children.

You'd make the container view slightly smaller than the screen so the parent view controller had room to display it's segmented control.

Comment: Do you know of any tutorials or examples further demonstrating this?  It sounds like what I should have been doing all along.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a segmented control to move between controllers, you're going to need to use different logic from what you have in your question. If you're selecting an index that's greater than the one you're currently on, you want to present the view controller, if you're going to an index that's less than the current one, you should dismiss or use unwind segues. If you need to go back more than one controller, then using an unwind segue might be the best way to go.